# NSDateFormatter in View based NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, osx-lion

I can't figure out how to set an `NSDateFormatter` for a static text table cell view in Interface Builder using the new view based `NSTableViews`. Since the problem is Interface Builder related, here are the steps to recreate the setup in Interface Builder:

1. Create Table View
2. Change *Content Mode* to *View Based*, name one column *Date* and have it contain static text views.
3. Fill the table with some test data (one column should contain dates)
4. Create a `NSDateFormatter`, in settings, set the *Date Style* to *Short Style*
5. Open the Static Text View for our date and set the formatter to the `NSDateFormatter`.

I seem to always get the default date formatting. How do I apply the date format to the dates in the table?

Comment: Trying to copy your setup. I do not see any text in my table... How did you set up the test data? Just filling in the Static Text Field and Text Field Cells I suppose.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution was actually very simple with the latest XCode 4.3.1:

- In Interface Builder, drag a Date Formatter into the target cell (so it becomes it's child)
- Set the date format for the Date Formatter

No additional wiring was required. Hope this helps somebody else running into this.

Comment: What an oddly useful and counter intuitive code-free solution.